# Allman-Style in Intelliji

Tags: intellij-idea

I was wondering how I might configure Intelliji IDEA to automatically make my code look like:

```
public void Something()
{
// something
}
```

rather than:

```
public void Something() {
// something
}
```

I believe it is called the "Allman" style. Intelliji comes out of box using the "K&R" (I think?) style, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

go to project settings. configure code style formatting.

Answer (score 1):

To do Allman for Java (newbie-ish version) go to File/Settings/Editor/Code Style/Java. Next select the Wrapping and Braces tab and expand Braces placement. Now you must click 'End of line' for all three choices and select 'Next line' for each in the box that appears. Then click apply and OK.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is already answered, but to save people from actually modifying the settings.

Here is the [AllmanIndent.xml](https://gist.github.com/SandeepGamot/c07825621f1add342d177ad3ab2d43b8) download the `.zip` file.

After you download and extract the zip do the following steps:

From IntelliJ go to File->Settings->Editor->Code-Style and click the gear icon by the "Scheme" and then click on "Import Scheme -> IntelliJ code style XML" and then choose the extracted `.xml` file.

After this import, you can press `Ctrl+Alt+L` to auto-indent code.